# which stack to choose for web development

Tags: webpack, web-scraping, web-applications, webview, webforms

I am currently doing Angela Yu's web development course.
I am leaning towards MEAN stack.
what advice would you give.
I also want to start freelancing.
Which platform would be right?

Comment: Although this question is not related to this platform but my suggestions are these platforms: Perfectlancer.com, Upwork.com, Freelancer.com, Guru.com

Answer (score 0):

Please ask specific questions that can have very specific answers. Yours is more more of an opinion oriented answer. We want stack overflow to mainly be about finding solutions to specific problems.

However, my advice to you is to start with whatever it is you find easiest. The MEAN stack is quite popular, and the benefit of starting with that is you will find solutions to your questions in SO easily. Once you develop your confidence and understand with one stack (its pros and cons), then you can do research do find something that fits your needs and work style. Be warned, though, that there is no holy grail of stacks, meaning that there is no 1 stack that will be the best at solving every problem. They all have pros and cons, and it is your job as a freelancer to know a wide variety of technologies so that you can pick the best one for your client.

I hope this helps.